# How to autofocus text box within a sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, css, autofocus, sidenav

So I'm using a sidenav with a textbox in it, similar to that of this example code from w3schools:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#"><input type="text" autofocus="autofocus"/></a>
    </div>
    
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
     $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {closeNav()} // escape
      if (e.keyCode == 83) {openNav()}  //s
    });
    </script>

   
         
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to autofocus the textbox when the sidenav is opened. Using `autofocus = "autofocus"` doesn't seem to work (like I tried in the example above). I also want it to work in combination with the keyup function I defined in the code (press 'esc' for closing and 's' for open). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give **id="f"** to **input** tag
And
In open nav function

**document.getElementById("f").focus();**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#"><input type="text" id="f"></a>
    </div>
    
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    
    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("f").focus();
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
     $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {closeNav()} // escape
      if (e.keyCode == 83) {openNav()}  //s
    });
    </script>

   
         
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works fine when I use it in Tryit Editor and it's an easy solution, but it doesn't work when I implement it in my own design. So I guess one of my other scripts (probably some js somewhere) is conflicting with it.

Comment: I forgot to clear cache ... ;p Thanks for the solution

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score -1):

You can change your `openNav()` function to something like this

```js
function openNav() {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    sideNav.style.width = "250px";
    
    var input = sideNav.getElementsByTagName("input")
    
    if (input && input[0]) {
      input[0].focus()
    }
}
```

and you'll be good to go :)